# How to set up Safe transaction service for forked ethereum mainnet testing?

Tags: multisignature, gnosis, safe-core-sdk

I am forking mainnet so that I can simulate a proposal to a DAO via multisig that I do not own, using hardhat, ethers, and typescript.  When I create a transaction, there's no way to set up a Safe transaction service for an L1 mainnet fork to my knowledge--the safe-infrastructure repository in github appears to be L2 only.

How can I test multisig transactions on a forked mainnet for a multisig I don't own?  The Safe transaction service doesn't work for my local hardhat fork, and I can't run an L1 tx service locally.

Edit in response to comment: SafeService is part of `'@safe-global/api-kit'` and is a programmatic way to connect to a Safe transaction service that manages signatures and proposals.  However, initializing the SafeService requires the URI of the service itself, like 'https://safe-transaction-mainnet.safe.global', which is listed on Safe's website.  It's a separate service on some cloud server.

I'd have to run a local version of the minimal tx service backend from this repo: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure BUT it's only for L2s!  So no forked mainnet, I don't think? Any ideas?

Comment: Where are the signature code/patern used?

Comment: Please see clarification above in question body.